# How to append comments as a row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have created an empty dataframe as below:

```
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['issues'])
empty_df
```

I want to append all my warnings under the column "issues" in the dataframe created above. So in the below code if the condition is met, I need to have the logging message to be appended as a row in my empty_df dataframe.

For example:

```
missing = (set(params["MRO pmd_name"][pd.notnull(params["MRO pmd_name"])].tolist()).difference(merge["pmd_name"][pd.notnull(merge["pmd_name"])].tolist()))
if missing != set():
    print("pmd_name missing is:", missing )
```

In the screenshot below I want "pmd_name missing is: {'abc'}" string to be added as row under "issues" column of empty_df:

[image]

Comment: please provide an example with data and expected output

Comment: updated my question

Comment: also, try to avoid images, we can't use them to create an example of our own